# How to get an ArrayList Value in another function?

Tags: java, methods, arraylist

I'm new to Java so i'm pretty confused about some logics. I have an array list (for a object or not) and then I want to execute a kind of function (what's it's called?method? i.e.functionExample) and get the value from the ArrayList.
Here's a sample code. Sorry if I'm not clear. I think im missing the public and things. (don't bother with no var initialization and declarations...)

```
package sampleclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleClass {

    public static void functionExample(){
        display = obj.add("something");

        System.out.println(display);

        //or
        obj.get(1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Class> obj = new ArrayList<>();

        functionExample();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check here: [Java Tutorials. Passing Information to a Method or a Constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html)

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I think your comment would make up a good answer; maybe except the fact that for sure this question must be have multiple duplicates on SO.

Comment: @EddyG Sorry, but it's not good to post link-only answers on the site.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Well, then one or two lines more would still make it an answer, or ;-)

Comment: check the scope of your variable.

Comment: @OwenBringino I'm not very experienced, how do I make ArrayList avaible for all my functions?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I checked and did not find exatcly anwser...can you make a anwser with a little example? Thanks all

Comment: Ok. Since your `functionExample` method is declared as static method, try to upgrade your `obj` list as static class variable.

Comment: @Stephenloky In your current code, `obj` (btw: a bad name for a LIST, you could call it myStrings for example) is "scoped" within the main method. If you want to use everywhere in your class, you have to move the declaration **outside** of the main function.

Comment: @EddyG Where should I exatly declare it? Can I declare it like below `import java.util.List;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go!! Try to explore the code.

```
package sampleclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleClass {

   public static void functionExample(List<String> obj){
      obj.add("something");
      obj.add("nothing");

      System.out.println(obj);

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      List<String> obj = new ArrayList<>();

      functionExample(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: Any JAVA reference for learning these "attributes" passing? Thanks again!

Comment: @Stephenloky I would humbly suggest a different approach: don't try to do trial-and-error on stackoverflow. Either you should buy a good book on Java; or at least you should turn to the Oracle tutorials; and start reading and learning (starting with "Getting started" and "Learning the java language"). You have to **learn** a language; and the first choice for learning is **studying**. Long story short: start here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html or here: http://www.mkyong.com/featured/top-5-free-java-ebooks/

Comment: @EddyG Yes Eddy great tip but i'm already studying, part of study is testing I think...I've made some tests and I'm just trying to fix the new Java logics in my head. But I got what I wanted. Thanks for the websites and tips! Certainly Im reading a book.

Comment: @Stephenloky I guess what I am saying is: you might be a little bit to early in "trying" things. Sometimes it makes more sense to first learn about the whole concept before starting to "try". It might seem more boring; but most likely you will save a lot of time and frustration. Its like when you buy one of these Swedish furniture things: **always** read the complete howto-build ... before starting.

Comment: @EddyG sure hehe I agree. Tks

Answer (score 1):

```
package sampleclass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SampleClass {

  public static void functionExample(List<String> obj){
    // Adding items to arrayList
    obj.add("something");
    // Adding items to arrayList by position
    obj.add(2, "Something more by position");

    //removing data
    obj.remove(0);

    // Checking index of an item
    int pos = list.indexOf("Item2");

    // Checking if array obj is empty 
    boolean check = obj.isEmpty(); 
    System.out.println("Checking if the arraylist is empty: " + check); 
    // Converting ArrayList to Array
    String[] newArray = obj.toArray(new String[obj.size()]);
    System.out.println("My new great array: "  + Arrays.toString(newArray)); 


    // Getting the size of the obj 
    int size = obj.size(); 
    System.out.println("The size of the list is: " + size); 

    //using foreach loop
    for (String str : obj) {
        System.out.println("Item is: " + str);
    }

    // Replacing an element
    obj.set(1, "My Element 1");
    System.out.println("The arraylist after the replacement is: " + obj); 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Class> obj = new ArrayList<>();

    functionExample(obj);
  }
}
```